# Pass Index from Carousel Widget to Another Widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, indexing, state, carousel

I am new to Flutter and stumped on how to do this. I have a screen that has a Carousel Slider widget on it that I am holding in a separate file/widget to keep the code as clean as possible. To that Carousel I am passing a List which are urls of images and videos. I have already implemented an indicator bar and have the index of the list held within `activeIndex` variable within the Carousel widget. I then need to pass that index value to a separate widget held in a variable on the main page of my app (one with the clean code).

I basically need help on where to define variables in one widget that I can then define and pass to multiple other widgets. Please let me know if you need more context as I am new to coding in general. Thanks!

Carousel Widget

```
class AssetCarouselBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const AssetCarouselBuilder({
    @required this.assets,
    this.activeIndex
  });
  final List<String> assets;
  final int activeIndex;

  @override
  State<AssetCarouselBuilder> createState() => _AssetCarouselBuilderState();
}

class _AssetCarouselBuilderState extends State<AssetCarouselBuilder> {
  int activeIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        CarouselSlider.builder(itemCount: widget.assets.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex){
          final assetUrl = widget.assets[index];
          options: CarouselOptions(
            onPageChanged: (index, reason) =>
            setState (() => activeIndex = index)
          //this is where I am holding the variable 'activeIndex' that I need elsewhere
          if (assetUrl.contains('jpg')) {
          return buildImage(assetUrl, index);
          }
const SizedBox(height: 5),
        buildIndicator(),
Widget buildImage(String imageUrl, int index) => Image(),
Widget buildIndicator() => AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
      activeIndex: activeIndex,
      count: widget.assets.length,
  effect: ColorTransitionEffect()
```

Implementation of Carousel on "main page"

```
class FeedPageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const FeedPageWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FeedPageWidgetState createState() => _FeedPageWidgetState();
}

class _FeedPageWidgetState extends State<FeedPageWidget>
  int _currentIndex = 0;

AssetCarouselBuilder(assets: listViewPostsRecord.postAssets.asList())
```

And then widget I need to pass the index to another widget on the "main page".

```
ShareMenuWidget(
postRef: listViewPostsRecord,
assetIndex: _currentIndex)
```

Any help on how I get the "activeIndex" value on the setState function in the Carousel slider is very appreciated!

Comment: In simplify, the question is how can i get carousel  active index?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes that is correct. I have the carousel active index held in the variable 'activeIndex' but that is only accessible in the Carousel widget. I am trying to figure out how to access that in other widgets on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callback method like `Function(int activeIndex)? onIndexChanged;`.

```dart
class CarouselCW extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(int activeIndex)? onIndexChanged;
  const CarouselCW({
    Key? key,
    this.onIndexChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CarouselCW> createState() => _CarouselCWState();
}

class _CarouselCWState extends State<CarouselCW> {
  final CarouselController carouselController = CarouselController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CarouselSlider.builder(
      itemCount: 4,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, int realIndex) {
        return Text(
          index.toString(),
        );
      },
      options: CarouselOptions(
        onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
          if (widget.onIndexChanged != null) widget.onIndexChanged!(index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And while using this widget you will get

```dart
CarouselCW(
  onIndexChanged: (activeIndex) {
    print(activeIndex.toString());
  },
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This allowed me to access the index outside of the widget build. I had to do a little more though to get the slide still to work, but was able to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you out. You can also check about `typedef`.